# Ввести строку s и число повторений строки n, вывести строку n раз с помощью цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Python. Введи строку s и число повторений строки n. Выведи строку n раз с помощью цикла. Где ошибка? Почему не работает?

```
s = input("Введи строку:")
n = int(input("Сколько раз повторить?"))
 while s < str(n):
    print(s)
    n = n + 1
```

Comment: покажите, что вы уже пробовали.

Comment: вот посмотрите, написал

Comment: Не работает, потому что условие для цикла while написано наугад, "напишу что-нибудь, авось получится".  Там написана лютая дичь.

Comment: Если не принципиально, можно без цикла: `print("Моя строка\n" * k)` где `k` - число повторений

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
s = input("Введи строку: ")

n = int(input("Сколько раз повторить? "))


for i in range(n):
    print(s)
```

---

```
while n:
    print(s)
    n -= 1
```